# How to dynamically target contents to users?

Tags: algorithm, rule-engine

In my project, there is a feature call content targeting.

For example, admin can configure that a content will only be available to users who met several conditions: female, age > 20 and live in New York. Admin can change the condition at any time, admin can also put condition on other fields. Each content can have different conditions.

I am studying rule engines but do not feel that is a right tool for this requirement. Is there any tool or framework is designed to resolve this problems?

Comment: What's wrong with rule engines?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi In the rule engine, we validate data against on rules at a time. In my case, each time user load the page, I need to validate user's data agains all rules of all contents to get list of satisfied contents. I thinks it could cause performance issues

Comment: In any rule engine worth its salt, only the rules specific to that user should be evaluated. if the rules are crafted properly.

Comment: In my case, once the application received information of a user, it must run all rules (0 - 100) against user's info to check what content suitable for that user. So I am worrying about the performance.